# Mongoose collection.update does not update the document

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb, mongoose

I am having an issue using Mongoose's `update` function. Basically the document I am trying to modify is not getting updated.

Here is the code:

```
  const user = 'Joe Bloggs'
  const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt()
  const pwStr = 'simplepassword'
  const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(pwStr, salt)

  User.update({user_name: user }, { $set: { password: hashedPassword }}, function(err, doc) {
    if (err) console.log('Error ', err);
    console.log('Updated Doc -> ', doc); // returns un-updated doc
  });
```

As you can see there is not much to it. The only thing I thought could be causing an issue was the `bcrypt` functions, but they seem to be working and `hashedPassword` logs out fine.

The callback logs the document, but it is not updated and when I check it in the Mongo shell it is indeed not updated.

I previously tried `findOneAndUpdate` but it appears that has been deprecated.

So, I tried `findOne`, but this also failed to update the document. Here is the basic code which uses `save` on the found user instead.

```
User.findOne({user_name: user}).then(async function(user) {
      user.password = 'easypassword';
      await user.save();
    } 
});
```

I tried using `update` in the shell using the same `{ $set: {...}}` syntax and it works.

If anyone can tell me why this operation isn't working when I try to do it using the Mongoose functions I'd much appreciate it. Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

I have tried the suggested code below:

```
const res = await User.updateOne([filter], [query]);
```

This returns the following when `res` is logged out:

```
{ acknowledged: false }
```

This appears in [MongoDB documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/glossary/#std-term-write-concern) to relate to a "write concern" setting, but I have no idea where to go with it from there.

Comment: The proper current way seems to be `const res = await User.updateOne([filter], [query]);` When I try this, the db object changes just fine. Also double-check that the keys are actually called `user_name` and `password`.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I tried it out but it still didn't solve the problem. When I console.log the `const res`, I get `{ acknowledged: false }`, and the document still doesn't update.

Comment: You're right, it worked exactly once for me then never again.

Answer (score 0):

`update` is what is actually [deprecated](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/deprecations.html).

`findOneAndUpdate`, like other `mongoose` update methods, it returns the un-updated object by default. Setting the option `new` to `true` will return the updated doc.

Another option would `updateOne`;

```
  User.findOneAndUpdate(
    { user_name: user },
    { $set: { password: hashedPassword } },
    { new: true },
    function (err, doc) {
      if (err) console.log("Error ", err);
      console.log("Updated Doc -> ", doc);  
    }
  );
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately, I have tried `findOneAndUpdate` and it still doesn't update the document. `{ new: true }` returns the unmodified document and it is also unmodified in the DB itself.

Comment: Ok, perhaps something else is going on then that I can't see, not sure. That function returns an updated doc on my end, and when I omit `{ new: true}` it returns the old version, which is the expected behavior.

Comment: Sorry I spaced on the fact that you already tried that before I answered. I edited my answer just for clarity  for anyone else that ends up here.